# Trying to run JavaFX 12 on NetBeans 11

Tags: java, macos, javafx, netbeans

I am trying to get JavaFX 12 to run on NetBeans 11. I have configured JavaFX to to my Project Classpath, and added `--module-path /Users/myname/Downloads/javafx-sdk-12/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` to the VM options, but it gives me the error upon running the main .java file:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found /Users/myname/Library/Caches/NetBeans/11.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line: /Users/myname/Library/Caches/NetBeans/11.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:68: Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

I am using Java 12 and JavaFX 12, with NetBeans 11.1 on a MacBook Air.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT:**
I tried with `netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home"` and it launched, but still showed the error.

Comment: It looks like the executor can't find Java. Did you set `netbeans_jdkhome`? See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans

Comment: @JoséPereda The one in `etc/netbeans.conf`? When I added `netbeans_jdkhome="/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home"` to it, the program refused to launch. Without it, it launches just fine

Comment: Remove quotes and try again

Comment: Nope, tried without quotes, without `/Contents/Home`, with `Contents/Home/lib`, without `.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: This is my conf file: `netbeans_jdkhome=/Users/<user>/Downloads/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/`

Comment: I tried like you said, redownloading the `jdk-12.0.2.jdk into the downloads folder and copied your conf file path but sorry, it did not work. (but it launched)

Comment: Ok, at least it launches, so you should have a different issue. Try to run a regular Java project without JavaFX?

Comment: One other thing you can do: remove the cache. Maybe you imported it from a previous version.

Comment: From command line type java -version.